# Is there a wmctrl command that terminates the "Always On Top" status of a window?

Tags: command-line

I just learned that this command below helps you keep a window always on top in Ubuntu 22.04.

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above

However when you run it again, it doesn't terminate the "always on top" status of the window. So when you run it, it is irrevocable. I need another command setting it back normal as if you never ran that command. Or better, a merged command checking whether "always on top" is enabled for the active windows or not, if not enables, or if so disbles. Is there anyone can make a command something like that?